# Using Google Cloud AutoML Vision Model in React-Native

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-automl, automl

I am going to use a trained Google Cloud AutoML Vision Model for detecting an object and getting coordinates in React-Native.
I already trained the model but I should use the token for calling the trained model.
I can generate the token by using the `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`
But I think the token will expire and users can't call this API.
What is the best solution for this problem?

```
fetch(
      'https://automl.googleapis.com/v1/projects/(projectid)/locations/(locationid)/models/(modelID):predict',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Authorization:
            'Bearer (bearer token)',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          payload: {
            image: {
              imageBytes: base64Image.base64,
            },
          },
        }),
      },
    )
```

This is my code of react-native.
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you'd want to authenticate [with a service account](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/before-you-begin). This lets you download a `key.json` file that your program will be able to access if you `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path_to_your_key_file.json`. Alternatively, if you don't want to keep a key file on the client, you can create a REST endpoint (for example, using a Google Cloud Function or Firebase Function) that talks to the Vision API, which can handle, for example, rate limiting. Then your React Native app would hit your wrapper REST endpoint instead of the Vision API directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I call with key_file.json in react-native?